# Не отображается диалоговое окно в андроид 10

Tags: android, kotlin

не могу разобраться. Вызываю диалоговое окно на андроид 6, всё отлично работает, вызываю на андроид 11, тоже работает. А на андроид 10, не отображается диалоговое окно.
Вот код.

```
var dialog = Dialog(this)
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(1)
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.text_redact)
    dialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT.toDrawable())
    dialog.show()
```

Вот так отображается на андроид 6
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот так отображается на андроид 11
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разметка dialog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_image"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/purple_200"
        android:src="?android:attr/textCheckMark"
        android:tintMode="src_atop"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.98"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tint="#EC0606"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextMultiLine"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="25"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.529"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.299"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="264dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextMultiLine"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp">


        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="302dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:max="100"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.152" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: код приложите текстом, покажите разметку диалога

Comment: не в комментариях, а в вопросе. Кнопка "править" под вопросом

Comment: из-за какого ограничения??? приложите код в вопрос, ограничений там на это действие нет

Comment: вам русским языком сказали какую кнопку нажать чтобы добавить код, а вы все-равно все в комменты набросали!

Comment: @Эникейщик, готово

Comment: @Andrew, готово

Comment: попробуйте использовать AlertDialog.Builder (из androidx.appcompat.app пакета!!), либо MaterialAlertDialogBuilder

Comment: Что за магическая константа 1? `dialog.requestWindowFeature(1)` У всех window features есть свои именные константы.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, но ведь не запрещено ставить цифры

Comment: Не запрещено, но ухудшается читаемость кода.